# Why unit test coverage data changing when I am using ?? (null coalescing operator)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have created an Employee model with id and name as optional properties and a description method which will return a interpolated string.

Here is its code:

```
class Employee: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    func description() -> String {
        return "Employee ID: \(id ?? "") and Employee Name: \(name ?? "")."
        //return "Employee ID: \(id != nil ? id! : "") and Employee Name: \(name ?? "")."
    }
}
```

and I have written test case for unit testing this Employee model.

Here is its code:

```
class EmployeeTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testEmployee() {
        let employee = Employee(id: "1", name: "Yash Vyas")
        XCTAssertEqual(employee.id, "1")
        XCTAssertEqual(employee.name, "Yash Vyas")
        XCTAssertEqual(employee.description(), "Employee ID: 1 and Employee Name: Yash Vyas.")
    }
}
```

I am not getting why coverage is 100% for Employee class when I use ternary operator instead of ?? (the commented line in the description method) for checking nil for optional properties when returning interpolated string from description() method and why it is reducing when I am using ?? (null coalescing) operator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another case like that solves the issue:

```
let another = Employee(id: "1", name: "Yash Vyas")
another.id = nil
XCTAssertEqual(another.description(), "Employee ID:  and Employee Name: Yash Vyas.")
```

Although that seems to me is either a bug on llvm or Xcode side.